# "I will meet" anapest substitute

Tags: word-choice, poetry, meter

I have the following song verse, which needs to be composed in Anapest (unaccented unaccented accented):

I will meet (i-WILL-meet)

Annabelle (an-nuh-BELLE)

In my dreams (in-my-DREAMS)

What would be a different way to say "I will meet" in a more anapest way? The third word should start with a plosive ( /P/, /B/, /K/, /G/, /T/, /D/ ).

Comment: *I will MEET AnnaBELLE in my Dreams.* is how I read that, so I *THINK* you're cor*RECT* in your Choice. :) or: see/greet/seek/find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm curious why you scan "I will meet" as an amphibrach in "I will meet Annabelle" rather than an anapest.  With all three words being monosyllabic, it's practically up to the individual where to place the stress, and to me it feels more natural to put it on the third syllable (thus avoiding a three-unstressed-syllable block afterwards).

That said, what about "I'm to meet Anabelle in my dreams?"  It implies compulsion rather than choice, but the word "to" is practically guaranteed to never be promoted to an accent.

Comment: You're right here. I think a better way to phrase the question would be a harder-sounding plosive anapest instead of the more mellow/nasal/non-plosive 'm' sound.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different in meaning, but gives the required anapest on the third syllable:

```
I will greet.
```